# 2 synonyms used in 1 sentence: makes up <number> % and constitutes <noun>

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

I’m wondering whether it looks well-written and, most importantly, grammatically correct to use 2 synonyms at once in my following sentence:

> Pacemaker Cells **make up** only about 1% of the Total Number of cardiac
>   muscle cells **and constitute** the Cardiac Conduction system.

If it looks well-written and is grammatically correct when the audience read it, do you recommend me using a ‘comma’ after ‘muscle cells’ to prevent it from sounding too long for a sentence?

> Pacemaker Cells **make up** only about 1% of the Total Number of cardiac
>   muscle cells **, and constitute** the Cardiac Conduction system.

Original Quote:

> ‘Pacemaker cells make up only about 1% of the total number of cardiac
>   muscle cells. There are three populations of these cells in the heart
>   that are capable of spontaneously generating action potentials and
>   setting the pace of the heart. These three cell populations are
>   collectively called the cardiac conduction system. After looking at
>   how pacemaker cells generate action potentials, we’ll cover the
>   components of the cardiac conduction system’ (Amerman 2019).

Thank you!

Comment: To echo a point in the answer, capitalizing the extra words is very strange. Also, even though you are only paraphrasing the original author, you still need to provide a citation. Something like (without quotation marks) *as Amerman says . . . (2019)*. Otherwise, it's plagiarism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question that arises is why you have introduced a series of capital letters where the original quote used lower case letters. There is no obvious reason for any of the capital letters other than the P that introduces the first word of the sentence.

As to the need for a comma, if you think that a reader should pause for a moment after the words **muscle cells** in order to better grasp or convey the meaning of the sentence, then use a comma. However, the presence or absence of a comma will not affect the apparent length of the sentence, only the sense of it.

Your choice of **make up** and **constitute** is perfectly idiomatic. The words fit the intended sense exactly.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. I thought it would be fairly annoying to read my sentence, as I felt I was basically writing "make up" 2 times. For e.g., "makes up __ and makes up ___". I'm concerned about putting a comma before "and". Would it be still grammatically correct? I've read about "parallelism", "the use of comma", and "conjunctions" for English grammar, but they can't address the issue. Usually a comma is added when there is a set of 3 verbs/nouns/adjectives.

Comment: For e.g.: There are three houses, two cars, and twenty people; It is red, blue, and purple; he can dance, run, and swim.

Comment: When the use of a comma assists a reader to better grasp the meaning of a sentence, use a comma. In your case, I believe it does. For example: **I spoke to John and Peter, and Susan listened in.** The presence of a comma after **Peter** makes it much easier to grasp the meaning.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. You're awesome!